# Android SQLite java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist

Tags: java, android, sqlite

here is how i create the table ...

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Product (
    _ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL  UNIQUE , 
    Name VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
    Code VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
    Quantity VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
    PRICE DOUBLE NOT NULL );"
```

if i do this.

```
myDb = new DbAdapter(getApplicationContext());
        Cursor res = myDb.getData(tbs.productsTable, tbs.getProductsColumns(), " ");    
        toast(res.getColumnName(0));
```

then it shows _ID, but when i do this:

```
ListView lvItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewProduct);
        Populate_Products todoAdapter = new Populate_Products(this, res);
        lvItems.setAdapter(todoAdapter);
```

it gives me this error:

> 03-14 19:36:52.459 31990-31990/com.example.danyalahmed.stockmanagement
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                            Process: com.example.danyalahmed.stockmanagement, PID: 31990
>                                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.danyalahmed.stockmanagement/com.example.danyalahmed.stockmanagement.Activities.ListProducts}:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
>                                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442)
>                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351)
>                                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
>                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5373)
>                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
>                                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
>                                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not
>   exist
>                                                                                                at
>   android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:303)
>                                                                                                at android.widget.CursorAdapter.init(CursorAdapter.java:172)
>                                                                                                at android.widget.CursorAdapter.(CursorAdapter.java:149)
>                                                                                                at
>   com.example.danyalahmed.stockmanagement.Classes.Populate_Products.(Populate_Products.java:20)
>                                                                                                at
>   com.example.danyalahmed.stockmanagement.Activities.ListProducts.loadData(ListProducts.java:52)
>                                                                                                at
>   com.example.danyalahmed.stockmanagement.Activities.ListProducts.onCreate(ListProducts.java:37)
>                                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442) 
>                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156) 
>                                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351) 
>                                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211) 
>                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5373) 
>                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020) 
>                                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)

Answer (score 3):

`Cursor` column names are case sensitive and `CursorAdapter` expects to see lowercase `_id`. (SQL identifiers themselves are not case sensitive.)

Either rename the column and recreate your table, or just select it explicitly in its lowercase form, e.g. `SELECT _id, ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Try **_id** instead of _ID in ***CREATE*** statement-

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Product (
_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL  UNIQUE , 
Name VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
Code VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
Quantity VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
PRICE DOUBLE NOT NULL );"
```